# How do I generate a new column subtracting the sorted one from the original in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my pandas DataFrame

```
>>> df
grades
0   69.233627
1   70.130900
2   83.357011
3   88.206387
4   74.342212
```

sorting it gives this

```
df.sort_values(by=['grades'])
grades
0   69.233627
1   70.130900
4   74.342212
2   83.357011
3   88.206387
```

I'm trying to get a new column `difference` that the value of each row comes the difference subtracting the sorted one from the original.

However, this code doesn't work

```
df['difference'] = df - df.sort_values(by=['grades'])
```

giving me

```
grades
0   0.0
1   0.0
2   0.0
3   0.0
4   0.0
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is expected, becaus epandas by default align by index values, so before subtracting reorder by original `df.index`, so get `0` values. for prevent it is possible convert values to numpy array and subtract only `Series` like:

```
df['difference'] = df['grades'] - df['grades'].sort_values().to_numpy()
```

If default index in original `DataFrame` also is possible set index to RangeIndex like:

```
df['difference'] = df['grades'] - df['grades'].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
```